# Удалить css link из DOM и добавить новый

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет.

Есть link, задача по нажатию кнопки на сайте перебрать все линки и удалить нужные а именно skin.css и screen.css и добавить новый weak.css

Как лучше это реализовать без помощи jquery?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/8862bcbe/css/jquery.mmodal.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/a16b7e4/css/jquery.mnotify.default.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/b4b7bb4a/jquery.mnotifyajax.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/22da6ae4/mtooltip.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/8e70d089/css/screen.css" media="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/8e70d089/css/skin.css" media="" />
```

Comment: и что не получается?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как это сделать без jquery чтобы не было проблем с отображением.

Comment: `Как лучше это реализовать с помощью jquery?` и `как это сделать без jquery` . Так что вам нужно то?

Comment: Как вариант, можно положить все необходимы линки на стили на страницу, и тем, которые изначально не нужны - поставить аттрибут `disabled`, а потом при нажатии на кнопку удалять и добавлять этот атрибут у тех линков, у которых есть необходимость

Comment: Ошибся в описании задачи сори, нужно без jquery у меня с js не очень, поэтому не могу понять как найти нужный link перебором, как его заменить/удалить и добавить другой, и нужно ли указывать сразу все линки в head?

Comment: И скажите, насколько большие эти файлы? Вам у одних и тех же блоков нужно поменять стили и вы для этого используете разные `css` файлы? Можно ведь разбить это все на классы, и опперировать методами `addClass()` и `removeClass()`. Плодить кучу `css` - не лучший вариант, тем более что рано или поздно вы прийдете к тому, что всех их нужно собрать в одну пачку и минифицировать

Comment: @msupreme А какими средствами вы хотите тогда это сделать если не `js`, какие у вас варианты?

Comment: Я реализую версию для слабовидящих для сайта поэтому решено было сделать двумя файлами css, структура сайта для слобовидящих отличается, поэтому так.

Comment: @Klimenkomud почему не js просто без использования jquery

Comment: @Klimenkomud если бы я знал как написать скрипт на js ,без плагинов, не стал бы задавать вопросы, но я не особо дружу с js, поэтому прошу помощи с написанием скрипта

Comment: @msupreme Так вам на `JavaScript` желательно, или всё равно? Если вы в целом с `js` не дружите, какая вам разница, будет оно написано с использованием библиотеки или без? У вас ведь всё равно какие-то библиотеки от `jquery` уже используются, так что вы в любом случае эту либу юзаете. Но в любом случае: добавьте все нужные линки на страницу, а c `js` я вам сейчас помогу

Comment: @Klimenkomud да хорошо добавил все стили в head 

выглядит вот так:


{% css 'css/screen.css' %}
{% css 'css/_base.css' %}
{% css 'css/weak-sighted.css' %}

Если поможете буду очень рад и благодарен)

Comment: Нужно на JS без использования плагинов

Comment: @msupreme Попробуйте для начала вариант из моего ответа. После того, как вы получите `html` с сервера, у вас должно всё стать наоборот(`weak.css` заработает, остальные будут иметь атрибут `disabled`). Если всё хорошо - то повешу это на кнопку

Comment: @msupreme Дополнил ответ, протестите

Comment: @Klimenkomud Давайте чтобы я понимал будем писать уже примеры кода

Comment: @msupreme Проверьте мой ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/8e70d089/css/screen.css" media="" id="screen_css_link"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/8e70d089/css/skin.css" media="" id="skin_css_link/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/8e70d089/css/weak.css" media="" disabled id="weak_css_link/>
<script>
    var button = document.getElementById('change_styles_button');
    button.onclick = function() {
        var screen_css_link = document.getElementById('screen_css_link');
        screen_css_link.disabled = True;
        var skin_css_link = document.getElementById('skin_css_link');
        skin_css_link.disabled = True;
        var weak_css_link = document.getElementById('weak_css_link');
        weak_css_link.disabled = False;
        alert('Styles changed to weak.css');
    }
</script>
<button id="change_styles_button">Плохо видите? Нажмите эту кнопку и всё волшебным образом преобразится.</button>
```

Comment: А можно реализовать без id в link и без атрибута disabled?

Comment: мне нужно перебрать все link выбрать из них нужные удалить и затем добавить новый - "weak.css" и ещё очень хотелось бы без onclick в button

Comment: Каким образом вы хотите, чтобы скрипт понимал, какие линки нужно убрать?

Comment: да в принципе.. Это довольно легко сделать... Смысла мало. Сейчас в ответе покажу

Comment: Напишите пож-ста код для перебора link

Comment: Я уже написал. А если коротко, то для выбора link по ссылке (href) используйте querySelector("[href='chto-to-tam']"). Если не знали о такой штуке, то советую почитать. Он позволяет делать выборку по css-селекторам

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log = function(vl) {//более удобны вывод списка link
  var elem = document.querySelector("#console");
  for (var i = 0, len = vl.length; i < len; i++) {
      elem.innerHTML += vl[i].getAttribute("href")+"<br>";
  }
  elem.innerHTML+="==========<br>";
};

console.log(document.querySelectorAll("link"));//проверяем, какие css подключены на данный момент(это не часть кода! просто для наглядности)

btn.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {//добавляем слушателя на кнопку
  var el = document.querySelector('[href="css/css1.css"]');
  if(el){//проверка на случай отсутствия нужного линка
  var created=document.createElement('link');//создаём новый link(для удобства можно уместить в отдельную функцию)
  created.rel="stylesheet";
  created.type="text/css";
  created.href="css/cssHZ.css";
  el.parentNode.appendChild(created);
  
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);//удаляем наш link(который в переменной el)
}
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll("link"));//опять выводим список css
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css4.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css5.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btn"> нажми на меня</button>
  <div id="console"></div>
</body>
```